# TensorFlow - Dynamic Input Batch Size?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In my case, I need to dynamically change the batch_size during training. For example, I need to double the batch_size for every 10 epochs. However, the problem is that, although I know how to make it dynamic, in ***input pipeline*** I have to determine the batch size, as the following code shows. That is, to use `tf.train.shuffle_batch` I have to determine the `batch_size` argument, and I do not find any ways to change it afterward. Therefore, I would appreciate any suggestions! How do you make a dynamic input batch?

```
  filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([self.tfrecords_file])
  reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

  _, serialized_example = self.reader.read(filename_queue)
  features = tf.parse_single_example(
      serialized_example,
      features={
        'image/file_name': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        'image/encoded_image': tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
      })

  image_buffer = features['image/encoded_image']
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer, channels=3)
  image = self._preprocess(image)
  images = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [image], batch_size=self.batch_size, num_threads=self.num_threads,
        capacity=self.min_queue_examples + 3*self.batch_size,
        min_after_dequeue=self.min_queue_examples
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is the following (I haven't tried this, so correct me if I make a mistake).

Create a placeholder for your batch size:

```
batch_size_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)
```

Create your shuffle batch using the placeholder:

```
images = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [image], batch_size=self.batch_size, num_threads=self.num_threads,
    capacity=self.min_queue_examples + 3*batch_size_placeholder,
    min_after_dequeue=self.min_queue_examples
  )
```

Pass in batch size with your call to `sess.run`:

```
sess.run(my_optimizer, feed_dict={batch_size_placeholder: my_dynamic_batch_size})
```

I expect `shuffle_batch` will accept tensors.

If there's any issue with that you might consider using the Dataset pipeline. It is the newer, fancier, shinier way to do data pipelining.

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets

Comment: Let me try it. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but it gives this error: `TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'list'> to Tensor. Contents: [None, 24, 24, 128]. Consider casting elements to a supported type.`
`

Comment: `numpy.array([your, list, of, values])` - you can't pass lists to tensorflow, you have to pass in numpy values.

Comment: Yes I know, but it occurs in a strange place. Before I change the batch_size to placeholder, everything works well. But after changing, the error above occurs in some network-building codes, which worked well before.

Comment: But can you check `type(your_input)` and validate it's a list. If so there's just a bug somewhere you need to track down.